# How to differentiate inner and leaf (final) nodes in a D3 dendogram

Tags: d3.js, hierarchical, hierarchical-clustering

I used D3.js to generate a dendogram where the user will see the results of a clutering. However, to keep the display clean, I would like the parent nodes to be kept as simple as possible (no text, no circle).

This is how the data is currently displayed: http://i.imgur.com/Cz52Fhl.png

And this is an example of how I would like it to show (the orientation does not matter, what matters is that inner nodes have not text or circle): http://i.imgur.com/Oo2A0b7.png

The code...

```
// Compute the new tree layout.
      var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
          links = tree.links(nodes);

      // Normalize for fixed-depth.
      nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 130; });

      // Update the nodes…
      var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

      // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
          .on("click", click);

      nodeEnter.append("circle")
          .attr("r", 1e-6)
          .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

      nodeEnter.append("text")
          .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
          .text(function(d) { return d.canonical; })
          .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it that you would like the ability to add a label next to the leaf nodes (the ones on the far right), with no label for any intermediary node?

If yes, there is is a live example at: http://bl.ocks.org/widged/5150104

Whether the node is of type inner or leaf is defined by this part of the code

```
  .enter().append("svg:g")
        .attr("class", function(n) {
          if (n.children) {
            return "inner node"
          } else {
            return "leaf node"
          }
        })
```

and later

```
var endnodes =  vis.selectAll('g.leaf.node')
    .append("svg:text")
    ... skipping attributes ...
    .text(function(d) { return d.data.name; });
```

Comment: Oh yes, but i'm using Clusterfck JS library and is very limited and generates information completely out of default. I have problems with this.
Know other libraries in JavaScript or PHP that have these algorithms (such as Euclidean distance and Mahalanobis Distance) implemented?

Comment: For euclidian distances, check out encog - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/477689/JavaScript-Machine-Learning-and-Neural-Networks-wi

Comment: And, if you can, help me in this question too please [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15421672/2146370)